# How to handle Luis intent with parameters with prompt

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have an intent in LUIS with several required parameters. I also set prompt for these parameters so that when they are not detected, LUIS asks for them. However in the BOT, I always get them as null when they are not specified.

The bot is not asking for the lacking parameters (even if the Prompts are set in Luis). Why? Is there a way to get the prompts automatically?
Or is that still not supported in MS Bot Framework?
I'm using C#

Comment: Are u using C# or Node?

Comment: I'm using C#, updated the question too

Comment: What version of the BotBuilder nuget are u using?

Comment: Version 3.0.0 and runtime version of v4.0.30319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment it seems you are using an older version of the Nuget package. Make sure to update to the latest BotBuilder version. Current version is [v3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/releases/tag/Nuget3.5).

In the latest versions, the BotFramework team added support for LUIS v2 API and added some brand new capabilitites. I'm pretty sure that V2 is now the default in the latest versions, but even that, the [LuisModel](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/8f0d6bbc1ef0fcef99b04560391384aba8fcde15/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/LuisModel.cs) attribute now accepts the [API version](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/8f0d6bbc1ef0fcef99b04560391384aba8fcde15/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/LuisModel.cs#L46) besides the ModelId and the ModelSubscriptionKey

For example, now the LuisDialog will act if your intent requires parameters and those are not provided. In that scenario (which it seems is yours), the LuisDialog will [automatically launch](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/8f0d6bbc1ef0fcef99b04560391384aba8fcde15/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L221) a [LuisActionDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/8f0d6bbc1ef0fcef99b04560391384aba8fcde15/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L286) and ask the user for the missing parameter, using the Prompt message you defined in the action parameter on the LUIS frontend.

BTW, to check for the action, you can to navigate through the actual intent. The [IntentRecommendation](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/Models/IntentRecommendation.cs) has an [Actions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/Models/IntentRecommendation.cs#L55) collection property.

The image below shows the full tree, including Action Parameters.

[image: Action parameters]

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to have a code example for how to use it?

Comment: You don't need to do anything on your code; it will automatically prompt for the parameters

Comment: I specifically mean, how to initialize the contstructor for instance (where do I get the context id from)?

Comment: You don't need to manually create a LuisActionDialog, it will be done automatically by the BotFramework as shown here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/8f0d6bbc1ef0fcef99b04560391384aba8fcde15/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L221