# BotFramework: How to handle multiple entities for a single Intent?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

In `LUIS` I have created some utterances for which `Intent` is detected and I have set 3 different `Entities` for it i.e For Example I am trying to build a bot to detect user's issue related to an application. So when User enters `Unable to Open Android` I have set intent as `Find_Issue` and `Entities` as 1.`Product` 2.`Issue` 3.`Error`. But since `Unable to Open Android` doesn't contain any error code. I am getting only `2 entities` `Product` & `Issue`. Now I want to get the value for  `Error` if no error it would be stored as none.
Here is the `Task` Code so far

```
[LuisIntent("Find_Issue")]
    public async Task getIssue(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        EntityRecommendation getProduct;
        EntityRecommendation getIssue;
        EntityRecommendation getError;
        if(result.TryFindEntity("Product",out getProduct))
        {
            chatdetails.issuedetails.product = getProduct.Entity;

        }
        if (result.TryFindEntity("Issue", out getIssue))
        {
            chatdetails.issuedetails.issue = getIssue.Entity;
        }
        if (result.TryFindEntity("Error", out getError))
        {
            chatdetails.issuedetails.error = getError.Entity;
        }

    }
```

`chatdetails.issuedetails` is the class created to store the values of `Product`,`Issue`,`Error`
I am not getting how to proceed further.

Comment: Your luis agent needs more training.

Comment: if the user's statement doesn't contain anything related to `Error` entitiy then it wouldn't get...but if it doesn't find the `error entitiy` it should ask user for the `error` related question.

Comment: @saikatmukherjee Train `Find Intent` more and if there is no entity you can use formflow to get answer for  `error` related question from the user

Comment: No need to use FormFlow. This is something that you can automagically do with Luis. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When defining an intent in LUIS you can also define it's Action Parameters. Action Parameters consists of a parameter name, an entity type, a prompt and if it's required or not.

[image]

Then, when using the latest version of the BotFramework Nuget package, your LuisDialog will automatically detect that a required parameter (as in your scenario with the Error entity) is missing and will automatically fire a prompt for the parameter, using the message defined in the Action Parameter.

For technical details about how this thing around the action parameters works, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697566/how-to-handle-luis-intent-with-parameters-with-prompt/41698888#41698888).